# Add id in handsontable cell

Tags: jquery, yii, handsontable

i am using handsontable jquery in my website,

I add id in each cell of that table,

but in scrolling time the datas are changes to different id,

how can i fill the id for every cell in handsontable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can't able to set id for handsontable..

But we can use onchange function..:-)